# jenkins run docker command get permission denied

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-plugins, docker-in-docker

i'm new to jenkins. currently i have a jenkins server start by docker with this docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    privileged: true
    user: root
    ports:
      - 50000:50000
    container_name: jenkins
    volumes:
      - ~/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /usr/local/bin/docker:/usr/local/bin/docker
```

then i created a simple pipeline to test the docker inside jenkins. This is the pipeline script:

```
node {
    stage "Create build output"
   
    sh "docker info"

}
```

and the error is the message below:

```
Started by user myuser
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/test-pip
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage (Create build output)
Using the ‘stage’ step without a block argument is deprecated
Entering stage Create build output
Proceeding
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker info
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/test-pip@tmp/durable-eb4fd6e4/script.sh: 1: docker: Permission denied
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 127
Finished: FAILURE
```

after checked some other topic, i already done all of these command:

```
chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock
```

```
sudo usermod -a -G docker $USER
```

but nothing works. i also install docker plugin for jenkins.
After get inside the jenkins container by this command:

```
docker exec -it 9729efd670b7 /bin/bash
```

i do the docker command:

```
docker info
```

but the console print out command not found:

```
bash: docker: command not found
```

does anyone know what should i config to make jenkins run docker? thank you.

Comment: can you run this command like this ```sudo docker info```

Comment: @DashrathMundkar i tried but the error change to : ``bash: sudo: command not found``

Comment: and my os is ``CentOS Linux release 8.4.2105`` btw

Comment: [jenkins 'execute script' build step Error: /bin/docker: Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42150870/jenkins-execute-script-build-step-error-bin-docker-permission-denied) is similar describes an SELinux-related issue.  Does that question help you?

Comment: (It's often better to install the `docker` binary using a package manager in a custom image's Dockerfile than to try to bind-mount the host's binary.  That could have missing shared-library dependencies or be for the wrong OS entirely.  Though, these problems wouldn't usually result in a "permission denied" error.)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But after correct the mount path to ``/usr/bin/docker``. now it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is some diferent posibilitites to run jenkins into docker, see details in this [link](https://www.tiuweehan.com/blog/2020-09-10-docker-in-jenkins-in-docker/).
Basically, there is three solutions :

1. Extend the jenkins image to install docker
2. Mount docker host to docker container
3. Run another image which contains docker-in-docker

In your case, you can use he second solutions, but since each solutions got advantages and inconvenients, you can try another.
Try to change your mount path to match the container path which should be `/usr/bin/docker`.

Comment: thank you so much. after i change the ``/user/local/bin/docker`` to ``/user/bin/docker``, now it works.

Comment: Changing from `/usr/local/bin/docker` to `/usr/bin/docker` works for me.

Comment: How to change path ? Any steps are there ?please send me

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://github.com/w7089/docker_in_jenkins) demo project where jenkins runs in docker container with docker client inside of it.

To have working docker client inside Jenkins container follow the below flow:

- build custom Jenkins Dockefile
- copy docker client inside custom Jenkins Dockerfile (for example, from [dind](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker/) image)
- expose host docker socket to Jenkins container using bind mount.

Answer (score 0):

It was a issue with the permissions to one of the volumes being used and I managed to solve this by changing one of the volumes to:

```
- /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker
```